# Java standalone program to decide the input source?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have java standalone utility which *greps* on the production servers to find the specific transactions. I wanted to extend the utility to run endlessly and to take inputs in a specific manner and process it and then go to the next input. This will be a list of search strings which the program will take as input and output the search results. And this program can continuously get data from this source.

The question is what could be the source of these search strings. I am currently thinking of SQLite DB from which the program queries and more search string can be added independently.

I am looking for better suggestions.

Comment: Give us some more information. Where do these search strings come from? Are they all manually typed in or can they be evaluated or sth? If they would be entered manually, a little SQLite DB can do the job, you could even keep the values in an array in your program (but if you want to keep the values after a crash, you'll need to store them somewhere)

Comment: give more information like the purpose of that.Why r u doing that and in which things this is used

Comment: These search strings are keywords used for investigation the system issues ( they could be session id's). Currently they are manually typed in. The over all purpose is to investigate system related issues.